# CSS: Flex Container with 3 divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a little trouble using flex in CSS to align my divs the way that I'd like them to be. The diagram below shows how I'd like it all to be set out

[Layout Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Kn1.jpg)

Here's all my CSS and HTML uploaded [as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjwot3oy/) and as a snippet:

```css
    @font-face {
   font-family: Comfortaa;
   src: url("Comfortaa-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: Neue;
   src: url("HelveticaNeue-Thin.otf") format("opentype");
  }

  body {
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;

   background-color: white;
  }

  #topSegment {
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   width: 100%;
   height: 600px;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   background: purple; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgba(181,91,184,1), rgba(62,71,130,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(181,91,184,1), rgba(62,71,130,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, rgba(181,91,184,1), rgba(62,71,130,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(181,91,184,1), rgba(62,71,130,1)); /* Standard syntax */
  }

  #frontLogo {
   width: 369.9px;
   height: 350px;
   margin: 125px;  
  }

  #searchBar {
   flex: 1;
   margin-right: 125px;
   margin-left: 0px;
   margin-top: 75px;
   margin-bottom: 75px;
   background-color: rgb(74,74,74);
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 25px;
  }

  #weatherInformation {
   flex: 1;
   margin: 125px;
   margin-left: 0px;  
  }

  #weatherInformation p{
   margin: 0px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 300;
   color: white;
   font-size: 2em;
  }

  #underline {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 0%;
   visibility: hidden;
   animation-name: expand;
   animation-delay: 0.75s;
   animation-duration: 0.8s;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  @keyframes expand {
   from {
    width: 0%;
   }
   to {
    width: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
   }
  }

  #gradient {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 10px;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;

   background: white; /* For browsers that don't support gradients */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,0)); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,0)); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,0)); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
   background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0)); /*Standard*/
  }

  #content {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 900px;

   background-color: white;
  }


  /* Custom Scrollbar CSS */

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 10px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
   -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
   border-radius: 50px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background: rgba(150,150,150,1);  
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
   background: rgba(150,150,150,0.6); 
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="topSegment">
  <a href="index.html">
   <img src="Weather%20Icon.svg" alt="CGS Weather Icon" id="frontLogo" >
  </a>
  <div id="searchBar">
   <div id="outer">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="weatherInformation">
   <p>CAMBERWELL, MELBOURNE</p>
   <hr id="underline">
   <p>28&deg;</p>
  </div>
  <div id="gradient"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

I'm sure it has some really simple solution using a couple of lines to do with `flex` but I can't seem to work out what they are..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please specify what exactly do you expect to see and don't see. Your template and actual snippet look quite differently. Try also to ask a specific question. Best regards.

Comment: I don't think you should be using flex for this at all.

Comment: There will be a few markup changes, but what is the expected layout when the search bar/water info does not fit page width?

Comment: @poepje ...its easy to just say that. What would you recommend then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

peopje, I disagree!  Flex is PERFECT for this!  (Disclaimer:  I'm a Flex Evangelist, so Flex is perfect for everything.)  ;-)

I used your diagram to construct a solution.  What you're asking for in the left pane isn't possible.  You have fixed-height margins, and a fixed-height logo, yet want the area to be the full height of the screen.  See the problem?  SOMETHING has to be variable there.

So....I used two flex fill panels - one atop, and one below, the Logo container, to center the logo vertically, yet fill the screen vertically at the same time.  I'm pretty sure the visual effect is as you intended.

Everything else is precisely how as you requested.

Note:  I gave you a chunk of CSS at the bottom of the CSS sheet that you can copy-paste-reuse in all your projects to do CSS Flex management.  Flex is very powerful, and those few CSS classes reduce the work to triviality.

Caution:  It's UGLY!  I put borders around everything so that you can see exactly what's happening, so it looks terrible.  You'll of course remove/comment out the borders for real-world use.  The borders are very helpful during development, though.

Here you go!
https://jsfiddle.net/brebey/ya8rea0f/2/

I also have a more general-purpose Flex box demo here.  It shows how to do the oh-so-common three-pane layout to-to-bottom (header/content/footer layout), with the variable-width pane in any position (top/center/bottom), then within there (in the variable-height content pane), it shows the same thing done in the also-oh-so-common left-to right layout (menu/content/ads, etc.).  Here's that if you're interested.  https://jsfiddle.net/brebey/sm4amanj/

The magic of flex boxes is that they are the only mechanism in CSS that lets you freely add padding, borders, and/or margins to any of your Flex DIVs, and they work as expected, without producing rampant scroll bars.  The above demo shows that via check boxes that let you switch decorations on/off.

** Please Accept/Up-vote the answer if this helps you! **

NOTE:  I only did the Flex/Geometry part for you;  it looked like you had a good handle on the background/border/color part of the equation.  If you need help getting the right background/transparent/opaque sequences set up for the effect you're looking for, holler back and I'll give you a hand.

```
/* */
```

Comment: wow..thanks so much for all of this. It's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. With regards to the left pane and all the dimensions within it being fixed, I forgot to mention that in the diagram, the surrounding div isnt the entire page. That was another container that I also had at a fixed height. Either way, thanks a lot for your help :D this is exactly what I needed

Comment: @MatthewHarrison - glad I could help, and glad I got you exactly what you needed.  Long live the Flex Box!  Please take a moment to accept the answer as correct.